# Solve the functional equation $\left(f(x)\right)^2 - f\left(x^2\right)=2x$

Tags: functional-equations

$\forall x \in \Bbb R ,$ Find all functions that satisfy:
$$\left(f(x)\right)^2 - f\left(x^2\right)=2x$$

---

My solution:
$$f(x) \cdot f(x) - f(x \cdot x)=x+x$$

$$f(x) \cdot f(y) - f(x \cdot y)=x+y$$
$$f(x) \cdot f(0) -f(0)=x$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{f(0)}+1 $$
$x=0 \to f(0)=1$
$$f(x)=x+1$$

---

Comment: How do you justify going from $f(x) \cdot f(x) - f(x \cdot x) = x+x$ to $f(x) \cdot f(y) - f(x \cdot y) = x + y$?

Comment: $$f(x) \cdot f(y) - f(x \cdot y)=x+y$$ 
If we write $x=y$ in this equation, we will get the equation given in the condition. If this solution is not correct. I will be glad, if you explain why.

Comment: The fact that an equation holds when $x=y$ doesn't mean that it holds for all pairs $(x,y)$.

Comment: That's backwards. How can you conclude that in general for all $x,y$ just from the given condition that is true for $x=y?$ @Rehman

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(x)-(x+1).$

Then $f(x)^2=g(x)^2-2(x+1)g(x)+(x+1)^2$ and $f(x^2)=g(x^2)-(x^2+1).$

So:

$$2x = f(x)^2-f(x^2)= g(x)^2-2(x+1)g(x)-g(x^2)+2x$$

Or $$g(x)^2-2(x+1)g(x)=g(x^2).$$

When $x=0$ or $x=1,$ we have $g(x)=0.$

Comment: Going from

$$f(x)^2-f(x^2)=2x$$

to

$$f(x)f(y)-f(xy)=xy$$

is not at all justified. You cannot just freely change some parts of it but not others. **However** it is true that if a function satisfies the second equation, then it also satisfied the first; indeed as you pointed out we can go from the second to the first by taking $y=x$. This does mean that we can find **some** solution(s) by solving the second equation. This does not mean, however, that we will find all, as there could (potentially) be functions satisfying the first but not the second equation.

Comment: IF $f$ is not necessarily continuous, I think you can get uncountably many $f$ by defining $g$ positive on $(1/4,1/2)$ and $(2,4)$ and then extending to all of $\mathbb R^{\geq 0}.$ It takes s little work to get the negative values.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me how you know that $f(0)=1$.  Letting $y=f(0)$ we get $y^2-y=0$ which only tells you that $f(0)\in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: If the question was "find **one** such function," your answer would be fine. The question asked to find all such functions.

Comment: @lulu $$f(x)=\frac{x}{f(0)}+1$$ $\frac{x}{0}$ when $f(x)=0$, but there is no such expression.

Comment: You have not justified that form.  As others have remarked, you can't just add in the $y$ term as you have tried.

Comment: $f(x)=-\sqrt x$ is a solution

Answer (score 2):

For $x = 1$ you must have $f(1)^2 - f(1) = 2$, so $f(1) = -1$ or $2$ (EDIT: but $-1$ will make a real value for $f(-1)$ impossible, as QC_QAOA points out, so it should be $2$).  For $x = 0$,
$f(0)^2 - f(0) = 0$, so $f(0) = 0$ or $1$.
On $(\sqrt{2},2]$, and $[1/2, 1/\sqrt{2})$ let $f(x)$ be arbitrary with $f(x) \ge x+1$.
On $(2,\infty)$ and $(0,1/2)$ define $f$ by iterating $f(x^2) = f(x)^2 - 2 x$, and on
$[1/\sqrt{2}, 1)$ and $(1,\sqrt{2})$ by iterating $f(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{f(x)+2\sqrt{x}}$.
Note that in each case this preserves the property $f(x) \ge x+1$.
Finally, for $x < 0$ define $f(x) = \sqrt{f(x^2) + 2 x}$.

Comment: That's much easier than my equiva lent approach. But do we know all functions must satisfy $f(x)\geq x+1$ for $x$ positive?

Comment: You definitely need $f(x)\geq -2\sqrt x$ when $x$ is positive.

Comment: To define $f(-\sqrt{x})$, you need $f(x) \ge 2 \sqrt{x}$ when $x > 0$.  No, I'm not sure that you need $f(x) \ge x+1$ for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Partial approach. This will define a large class of answers that are not necessarily continuous.

Let $g(x)=f(x)-(x+1).$

Then $f(x)^2=g(x)^2+2(x+1)g(x)+(x+1)^2$ and $f(x^2)=g(x^2)+(x^2+1).$

So:

$$2x = f(x)^2-f(x^2)= g(x)^2+2(x+1)g(x)-g(x^2)+2x$$

Or $$g(x)^2+2(x+1)g(x)=g(x^2).\tag 1$$

So if we define $g(x)$ as a positive function on $(1/4,1/2)$ we can define inductively for $x\in [2^{-2^{k+1}},2^{-2^{k}}],$ as $g(x)=g(\sqrt x)^2+2(x+1)g(\sqrt x).$

And for negative $k$ and $x\in[2^{-2^{k+1}},2^{-2^k}):$

$$g(x)=-(x+1)+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+g(x^2)},\tag2$$
which is gotten by solving the quadratic equation $(1)$ and choosing the positive case.

We can choose either $g(0)=1$ or $g(0)=0.$ Likewise we can choose $g(1)$ from $1,2.$

This defines $g$ on $(0,1).$ We can define $g(0)$ as $0$ or $-1$ and likewise $g(1)$ as $0$ or $-3.$ But we need $g(1)=0$ since $g(-1)^2=g(1).$
Note that these definitions ensure $g(x)$ is always positive.

We can likewise define $g$ as positive on $[2,4)$ and again define inductively to get $g$ defined on all of $(1,\infty).$

Then the problem is the negative cases. But again, we can define the negative cases from $(2)$ again, except the problem is that some $g(x^2)$ might be negative.

So, we can find a large set of such functions if they don't have to be continuous.

I doubt these are ever continuous except when $g(x)$ is everywhere $0,$ but I might be wrong.

And this might not be all the possible examples, since this defines only the cases when $g$ is positive on the positive reals.

Answer (score 1):

I can show that $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)=2$ although I cannot use a similar approach to nail down a value for $f(0)\in\{0,1\}$:

---

Taking $x=1$ we have

$$f(1)^2-f(1)=2\Rightarrow f(1)\in \{-1,2\}$$

Taking $x=-1$ and both possibilities of $f(1)$ from above we have

$$f(-1)^2-(-1)=-2\Rightarrow f(-1)^2+3=0\Rightarrow \text{impossible}$$

$$f(-1)^2-(2)=-2\Rightarrow f(-1)^2=0\Rightarrow f(-1)=0$$

This also gives us that $f(1)=-1$ is impossible.